# Clear all the existing content in a row in jqgrid inline edit and open fresh input data fields.

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, inline-editing

My requirement is, If I click a row in jqgrid with inline edit feature. In edit mode, I don't want the existing cell content to be present. Instead the cell contents should be blank, so that user enters anything, that gets saved .

I am able to access cell contents using selected Id, but how do I clear it and set it in the edit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear for me why you need to have implemented such strange behavior. Probably an example could clear all. Nevertheless the requirements is not difficult to implement.

You can use `oneditfunc` parameter of the [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) to do some actions at the beginning of the editing. Because not only text input fields are possible, you have to do different actions for different controls. For example, in case of text input and the checkboxes the code could be the following

```
grid.jqGrid('editRow', rowid, true, function () {
    var $tr = $(e.target).closest('tr')[0],
        $selectedCell = $("input, select", e.target);

    $("input:text", $tr).val('');
    $("input:checkbox", $tr).prop("checked", false);
}
```

(where `var grid = $("#list");`). In case of other controls you have to implement additional actions.

See the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithInlineEditingWithClearInput.htm).

Comment: @Anoop: Is it what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

```
 beforeShowForm: function(form) {
   $("#Row id 1", form).val('');
   $("#Row id 2", form).val('');
 }
```