# Clear specific value in edit field when editing Row

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid in inline editing mode.

For a particular grid, I need that when I edit a row for some of the values to be displayed in the fields and for others to not.

For example I have a row with these values:

> col1 : 8h ;  col2 : 8h ; col3 : 8h ; col4 : V ; col5 : V ; col6 : V ; col7 : 8h ; col8 : 8h

When I click edit the row, I need it that when there is an "8h" in the cell the fields will be empty, and when there is "V" in the cell the fields will keep the "V".

I tried to use this response of Oleg: [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887164/clear-all-the-existing-content-in-a-row-in-jqgrid-inline-edit-and-open-fresh-inp/6890529#6890529)
But I am not able to distinguish the "8h" and the "V"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that I correctly understand your requirements. I suppose that you can change the line

```js
$("input:text", $tr).val('');
```

from the code of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6890529/315935) to something like

```js
$("input:text", $tr).filter(function() {
    return /^8h$/i.test($(this).val())
}).val("");
```

The expression `/^8h$/i` is [the regular expression](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) where

- ^ means matching the begin of the testing string
- $ means matching the end of the testing string
- /i at the end of the regular expression means case insensitive compare

So the above `filter` tests values of `<input>` elements and choose only the elements which contains is `8h` or `8H`. You can remove `i` at the end of the regular expression if you need case sensitive compare.